# its about what to do if you didn't install sublime when using ruby on rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did not install sublime. I'm at the point in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Hartl where he has you set up a branch for the first time. So I can't figure out what to do where his instructions are
$ git mv README.rdoc README.md
$ subl README.md

Should I create a file like the one in his book and then replace the original README.rdoc document and skip these commands? Should I create the new README.md file and put it in the main project folder but keep leave the old file there? If I do one of these can I then just continue with the rest of the commands after these? Should I do one of the above and then run just the first command above? The book doesn't seem to give a clue really about what is necessary here. It doesn't even actually tell you to create the new file. Honestly I'm lost here.

The only thing I think I understand is that the first command above renames the old file. If that is true then can I just run that command and then edit the original file in a text editor. Would I then skip the second command. Could I then continue with the rest of the commands.

By the way I working on a laptop running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git mv README.rdoc README.md
```

That is going to rename the file.  Nothing more.

```
$ subl README.md
```

That is going to open the renamed file in Sublime (a text editor).

If you want to achieve those two steps, just rename the file however you like and open the file in any text editor.